# Blender animation doesn't import in UNREAL ENGINE

Tags: blender, unreal

I've created a 3d model of a flag with the wind animating it. I saved it as a .fbx and imported it into unreal engine. All the meshes and texture are correctly imported but the animation of wind is missing. I've tried everything but the flag isn't moving.

I've tried to import a already made project (.fbx) downloaded from sketchfab and the animation is working fine. Am I missing something when exporting the file from blender? Or should I adjust something directly in Unreal Engine?